# Magento: receiving "table exists / error in file" error when viewing a page

Tags: magento

Running a clean install of Magento 1.8.1 with sample data. I've had a ton of issues with this whole thing. My current issue is a blank page when viewing a category. The page either loads blank, or removes all function of the previous page with a url change.

No errors appear when viewing the page. Problem currently persists on all navigational categories.

Viewing the "Reports" I find an error....

```
a:5:{i:0;s:263:"Error in file: "/data/9/3/59/144/3385633/user/3775743/htdocs/enigme/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/sql/catalog_setup/upgrade-1.6.0.0.9-1.6.0.0.10.php" - SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'catalog_product_entity_group_price' already exists";i:1;s:1196:"

#0 /data/9/3/59/144/3385633/user/3775743/htdocs/enigme/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(645): Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Error in file: ...')

#1 /data/9/3/59/144/3385633/user/3775743/htdocs/enigme/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_modifyResourceDb('upgrade', '1.6.0.0.9', '1.6.0.0.18')

#2 /data/9/3/59/144/3385633/user/3775743/htdocs/enigme/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(320): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_upgradeResourceDb('1.6.0.0.9', '1.6.0.0.18')

#3 /data/9/3/59/144/3385633/user/3775743/htdocs/enigme/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(235): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->applyUpdates()

#4 /data/9/3/59/144/3385633/user/3775743/htdocs/enigme/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(417): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates()

#5 /data/9/3/59/144/3385633/user/3775743/htdocs/enigme/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(343): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()

#6 /data/9/3/59/144/3385633/user/3775743/htdocs/enigme/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)

#7 /data/9/3/59/144/3385633/user/3775743/htdocs/enigme/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')

#8 {main}";s:3:"url";s:1:"/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

I've seen this error now on a magento db w/o sample data as well as WITH the sample data. I currently have 3 weeks remaining on this project and after convincing them to switch from opencart to something more "functional" the client refuses to use anything but Magento, does not want to switch to something else *again*. WHAT IS GOING ON?

Website for reference: http://enigmedesigns.com

EDIT: I have attempted flushing the catch, disabling compilation, adding `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to index.php, FULL reinstall, category/product deletion, I'm stumped.

Comment: Having little debugging experience in Magento before offering it to a client might have been your first mistake. Magento is a powerful beast but it does need a lot of careful handling.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure where such a conflict might originate from, looks like the upgrade script 
"upgrade-1.6.0.0.9-1.6.0.0.10.php" is failing to check whether a certain table exists respectively fails to drop it before trying to create it (I got those a lot on my custom DB tables >.> ).

Maybe Magento's DB access lacks the permission to drop tables?

IF not, maybe trying to install Magento CE 1.7 or 1.8.0 and then upgrade the installation to 1.8.1 might circumfence the problem for now, but chance is the same upgrade script chain is used and thus fails, too.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know what Magento is doing you should read this article written by the very knowledgeable Alan Storm: http://alanstorm.com/magento_setup_resources.

Basically Magento is working through its upgrade scripts one by one, version-step-by-version-step to get the database tables to the version it wants: 1.6.0.0.14.

The answer above from user3154108 about the Magento DB user lacking table drop permission is a good answer and well worth checking.

If you really want to struggle on with this then you might need to inspect the version numbers in `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/etc/config.xml`

```
<modules>
  <Mage_Catalog>
    <version>1.6.0.0.14</version>
  </Mage_Catalog>
</modules>
```

And, as per Alan Storm, check the version of `catalog_setup` listed in the database table `core_resource`. You might even try dropping the table `catalog_product_entity_group_price` manually and ensuring the value of `catalog_setup` in table `core_resource` is 1.6.0.0.9

**But, you know, I wouldn't be sleeping easy running a shop on a sketchy Magento install**. You should be able to cleanly install it. Perhaps talking to a dedicated Magento hosting company is the way to go. They will provide a clean install for you and I think your client will want a fully supported dedicated Magento host when it starts trading.

Or if you want to satisfy your sense of adventure try something like one of Pagoda box's pre-configured PaaS [Magento app instances](https://pagodabox.com/cafe/pagoda/magento-optimized) (hint: I don't think it runs very well on the free tier - Magento needs more oomph than that so I advise investing a few bucks to figure it out) (I haven't used it but I have one eye on it). Other PaaS Magento providers are available.

With three weeks left on your project [Magento Go](http://go.magento.co.uk/) might be a good option.